# Problem with WebIOPi and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, rpi.gpio, webiopi

I installed WebIOPi on my Raspberry Pi 3, I use the patch for Pi 2 and 3 from this Github repository: `https://github.com/doublebind/raspi`. I can run the WebIOPi service, and the webpage appears in my browser, but the buttons don't do anything.

When I initiate the service, it's suppose to appear a lot of scrolling data about what is happening, but in this case, some of that information starts to appear, but then it just stops.

Also, I know everything about the ports and how they changed, but I get the same result. I am trying to communicate with pins 8 and 10 (TX and RX).

What can I do?

EDIT: Another curious thing is that I run this command `sudo /etc/init.d/webiopi status` to see if the service is running or not. I get this:

`webiopi.service - WebIOPi
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/webiopi.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2016-08-04 16:15:45 UTC; 23min ago
  Process: 412 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -m webiopi -l /var/log/webiopi -c /etc/webiopi/config (code=killed, signal=KILL)
 Main PID: 412 (code=killed, signal=KILL)`

But I can see my html project, but with no response.

Comment: can you share your `/etc/webiopi/config` file. Maybe there could be some problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get response from the html webpage by modifying the Javascript code, but I don't really know why was that the problem. It worked perfectly in my Raspberry Pi 2.

The thing is that the patch for the Raspberry Pi 3 works fine.